# View [Me] in sharepoint 2013

Tags: view, filter, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to filter a document library for the logged user. 
I've a column person type and i tryed to use [Me] in the filter but without result. 
If i look inside [Me] i've #%<~

Do you have a solution to do this? 
Thanks

Comment: Does "i tryed to use [Me] in the filter but without result" mean that you're trying to filter a view? If so, try =[Me] with the equal(=) sign.

Comment: Can you provide a scrrenshot in some way for the filter condition?